Произвольная таблица в qt creator
Существует ли в qt инструмент, аналогичный кисти для рисования произвольных таблиц в ворде?
Если нет, то какие возможные варианты создания данной таблицы (необходимо чтобы вся таблица была одним виджетом, т.е. реализация в виде наслоения layot'ов и размещения label и line edit'ов не подойдет).

Нема. Все ручками. Была попытка втюхать сообществу что-то типа аналога DataGid из DevExpress, но разрабы замутили такую цену, что их похоже просто вcе послали. Да и очень давно это было, вот посмотри сюда http://www.prog.org.ru/index.php?topic=9537.0;prev_next=next или сюда https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=DevMachines.QtitanDataGrid
